# Передача параметра в GET-запрос

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, get

Такая ситуация. 
У меня имеется  GET-запрос.

```
- (IBAction)sendGet:(id)sender {

    NSString *tmenu = _textFieldGet.text;

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.ru/menu.php?tmenu=%@", tmenu];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [theRequest addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLConnection *connectionGet = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if(connectionGet){

    }
}
```

Таким образом у меня параметр, который принимается из текстовой строки, в которую пользователь вводит цифру от 1 до 4.

Так же у меня имеется `PickerView` с 4 значениями. Да, выглядит глупо, но мне обязательно categoryCollection нужен как Array.

```
categoryCollection = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Choose category", @"Group",@"Faculty", @"Teacher", @"Auditory",nil];
numberOfCategoryCollection = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];
NSDictionary *categoryDictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:categoryCollection forKeys:numberOfCategoryCollection];
```

После выбора какого-либо значения, оно отображается в `textField`.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

[_textFieldGet setText:[categoryCollection objectAtIndex:row] ];  // Отображает категорию в текстФилд}
```

В запрос мне надо передавать именно цифру, а в `textField` передается название, а не ключ. Как мне сделать так, чтобы для пользователя отображалось название варианта, а в запрос передавался ключ? Для этих целей я и создал `categoryDictionary`, думал, можно как-то использовать.

Извините, если слишком запутанно объяснил, это мои первые шаги в разработке. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

привет, если я правильно понял, тебе надо просто создать ассоциативную проверку, можно использовать if isEqualToString: и по результатам подставлять цифру. Вариант с ассоциативным словарем тоже не плох, поменяй местами ключи и значения или доставай ключ по значению (громоздко и проверки дополнительные нужны) , но есть варианты эффективнее в смысле производительности (если это важно).. в чем вопрос то? :)

Comment: Да, мне кажется именно подобная проверка мне и нужна. Только я немного не понял зачем менять местами ключи и значения. " или доставай ключ по значению" - вот я как раз этого и хотел добиться, только не особо получалось все. Спасибо!

Comment: тебе нужно по выбранной строке достать цифру, то есть выполнить такой код:      NSString numberForRequest = [aDictionary objectForKey:userString];  вот и все, у тебя цифра в зависимости от строки выбранной юзером, а у тебя сейчас наоборот, цифры являются ключами, а строки значениями.

Comment: У меня небольшая проблема, как я понимаю, с форматированием. Когда пытаюсь внести сюда данные из textField, то ничего не происходит.
`numberForRequest = [categoryDictionary objectForKey:@[@"%@",_textFieldGet.text]];`

Но когда задаю в явном виде, то все срабатывает. Не могу понять что не так.    
`numberForRequest = [categoryDictionary objectForKey:@"Group"];`

Comment: Попробуй просто: numberForRequest = [categoryDictionary objectForKey:textFieldGet.text]; или сначал NSString *aKey = textFieldGet.text; затем numberForRequest = [categoryDictionary objectForKey:aKey];

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй почитать про AFNEtworking:

- [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
- [AFNetworking 2.0 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial)
- [AFNetworking 2.0](http://nshipster.com/afnetworking-2/)

Можешь поставить плагин для проверки АПИ [r2m-plugin-ios](https://github.com/magnetsystems/r2m-plugin-ios).

Я делал так:

```
NSURL *urlBase = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:urlBase];
AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];

NSDictionary *parameters =  @{@"email": _textEmail.text, @"password": _textPassword.text} };

[manager GET:@"/api/categories" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Сходу не могу прикинуть и ответить то ли, что требуется. Сейчас почитаю про это, попробую разобраться. Спасибо большое!